# understand calculator code on Ios

Tags: ios, swift, calculator

I want to see how programmers explain this code, and What is the utility of the last line? 
I am a new beginner and I am not sure if I am understanding this code properly. Hope you are going to give nice detailed answers so I can get my benefit and also the other new beginners ever after.

```
var UserIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false
@IBAction func TouchedDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let digit = sender.currentTitle!
    let CurrentTextinDisplay = Display.text!
    if UserIsInTheMiddleOfTyping {
    Display.text =  CurrentTextinDisplay + digit
    }else{
        Display.text = digit
    }
     UserIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = true
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a brief explanation based on my interpretation of this fragment of code.**

*Apparently, before the method is executed we don't know if the user is typing anything or not since the method could have been already called, therefore `UserIsInTheMiddleOfTyping` could be either `true` or `false`*

> var UserIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false

When he taps a number on the calculator the method `TouchedDigit(_ sender: UIButton)` is triggered.

A new constant `digit` is created and set to the sender's title which is an instance of `UIButton` (The title property is the displayed name of the button, e.g. 1,2,3..)

A new constant `CurrentTextinDisplay` is created and set to the content of what I suppose to be a `UITextField` (Unwrapping it, therefore is not null)

> let CurrentTextinDisplay = Display.text!

If the user was typing something before the method was called (Pretty bad code implementation though), we append the `digit` constant created before to the content of the `Display` instance which (I guess) holds the digits already typed.

> if UserIsInTheMiddleOfTyping {
>       Display.text =  CurrentTextinDisplay + digit
>       }

Otherwise, if the user is entering the first digit, whe set the `Display` instance to hold this first `digit`

> else{
>           Display.text = digit
>       }

Before returning the method sets `UserIsInTheMiddleOfTyping` to true.
(Next time the method is triggered we will enter the if statement for sure and append the new digit.)

> UserIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = true

I would personally shrink the code as follows:

```
//There is no need to save in a variable if the user is in the middle of typing
//Because he will be in this state only when the method is triggered, therefore just shrink as follows:

@IBAction func TouchedDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //Safe unwrapping of sender.currentTitle:
    if let actualDigit = sender.currentTitle {

        //Safe unwrapping of Display.text:
        if let actualText = Display.text {

            Display.text =  actualText + actualDigit


        }

    }

}
```

Hope this helped, if so mark the question as correct.

Bye

Comment: Thank you Albert. That was very helpful and I appreciate you give time to explain it very detailed. I don't know why they down vote my question, like they weren't beginners one day. But Thank you so much Albert.

Comment: Glad I was helpful to you. Forget others and be yourself. Next time try to describe your problem deeper.